# Refresh SAS stored process in Excel with prompts

Tags: excel, vba, sas

The following VBA code runs a SAS stored process and places the results in an Excel spreadsheet, based on the value of EUID that an end-user types into cell C2. However, each time the user runs the macro, it just inserts a new dataset, pushing the previously-ran dataset to the right. Is there a way to revise the code so that it just refreshes the dataset with the new EUID each time, rather than inserting a new dataset? Thank you for your help.

EDIT: This is not the same as my other question. This is in regards with how to prevent a new dataset from being inserted each time the macro is run.

```
Sub InsertStoredProcessWithPrompts()
Dim sas As SASExcelAddIn
Set sas = Application.COMAddIns.Item("SAS.ExcelAddIn").Object
Dim prompts As SASPrompts
Set prompts = New SASPrompts
prompts.Add "EUID", activesheet.cells(2,3).value 'This is cell C2
Dim a1 As Range
Set a1 = Sheet5.Range("F2")
sas.InsertStoredProcess "/User Folders/Stored Process 1", c1, prompts
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to type SAS prompt value in Excel to run stored process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167184/how-to-type-sas-prompt-value-in-excel-to-run-stored-process)

Comment: No; I edited my question to clarify. This question involves the same code, but is about how two refresh a dataset rather than insert a new one each time the macro is run. Thank you.